# In atom vim mode how can I set ctrl+; to add ; to the end of the current line

Tags: atom-editor

In atom vim mode how can I set ctrl+; to add ; to the end of the current line?

This is very handy and I got used to it very much

Actually there are a few of things I need to set up..

```
map <C-;> A;<Esc>
nnoremap j jzz
nnoremap k kzz
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't use Atom vim mode, but you can use [this package](https://atom.io/packages/trailing-semicolon), and customize it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect such a package to exist